# Issue with realloc() for bigger string

Tags: c

I have the following c-code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char *str = malloc(5);
    str = "abcd\0";
    str = realloc(str, 9);
    if(str == NULL) {
        printf("Not enough memory\n");  
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    str = "abcdabcd\0";
    printf("%s\n", str);
}
```

The first 2 lines of the main method work fine, but when I try to reallocate Memory, it says that realloc() is an invalid pointer. What am I doing wrong?

By the way: Is it necessary to set a NULL character, if the string value is as big as the allocated momery block?

Thanks for help.

Comment: `str = "abcd\0";` doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: If a `realloc()` for 9 bytes fails you've got some serious issues. For trivial programs like this don't bother with checking for `NULL`. It's a waste of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your line

```c
str = "abcd\0";
```

isn't copying the string to the existing memory block that you mallocd; instead, it's making the pointer `str` point to a different location (the one containing the string constant).

Instead, do this:

```c
strcpy(str, "abcd");
```

Similarly, when you later change the contents of the string, you should do this:

```c
strcpy(str, "abcdabcd");
```

Note that you don't need to specify the null character explicitly -- it's always included in string constants automatically.

> By the way: Is it necessary to set a NULL character, if the string value is as > big as the allocated momery block?

Yes, strings always need to be terminated with a null character. C doesn't have any way of "knowing" where the memory block ends.

Comment: Another fix: `char *str = strdup("abcd")` to make a mutable, allocated copy.

Comment: "Mutable" meaning you can change the four characters, but you can't change it to a five character string, so it's highly dangerous if you plan to make changes.

Comment: @gnasher729 That's where the `realloc()` comes in.